# Dynamic variable with HTML and multiple iframes in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an Ionic app that is calling an API. The API is giving me some HTML content like this:

```html
<h1>test</h1>
<p> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8L6p2NnAMvE" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8L6p2NnAMvE" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But in the app, the YouTube video's are automatic reloading because I don't trust the urls with sanitizing. How can I do this for an variable that has dynamic HTML with iframes?

Comment: What do you mean by *'automatic reloading'*?

Comment: Its refreshing the iframe after a few seconds, so If you play the video. After 3/4 seconds it's reloading so the video stops. This is continue, 10 sec later it's again reloading the iframe..